# How to get screen identification number from Screen class

Tags: c#

i need to show dialog in screen by its identification number, for example i have this situation
[image: screen setup on windows]

I want to show something on fourth, when i get all screens by using Screen.AllScreens, my fourth screen is 0 element in array, because AllScreens returns screens not by indent number but by squence.
So mayby someone knows the way how to get identification number from Screen class, or how to get screen coordinates and bounds by its identification number.

UPDATE:

DeviceName is not always corrspont to identification number (see image below):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `screen.DeviceName` you should get `\\\\.\\DISPLAY1`, `\\\\.\\DISPLAY2`, etc. You can use this to search for `\\\\.\\DISPLAY4`.

Comment: Hi again your solution is not working, i updated my question with image on which identification number is not eqvivalent to devicename number.

Comment: This wont work. On my PC I have Screen 1 and 2, yet their DeviceNames are Display3 and Display4.

Answer (score 0):

To get screen number (dirty way, but it works):

```
 var sceenId = -1;
 var targetScreen = Screen.FromPoint(Cursor.Position);
 for (var i = 0; i < Screen.AllScreens.Length; i++)
 {
     if (!Equals(targetScreen, Screen.AllScreens[i]))
         continue;
     sceenId = i;
     break;
 }
```

To get screen coordinates and bounds by its identification number:

`Screen.AllScreens[sceenId].Bounds`